# Should two people in the same household share an account?

Tags: discussion

Should two people like my little brother and I share the same account or should I allow him to have his own account (I've done this before and failed horribly) and allow him to learn the rules of the website on his own and allow him to make the same mistakes I did?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He can have his own account, provided that he is at least 13 years old.

What he can't do is upvote your posts (or you his) solely because you're brothers.

Comment: He's 8 and I'm fully aware what we did was wrong and will never happen again.

Comment: @YoungGuilo: While there's nothing wrong with brothers having multiple accounts. (Both my brothers have separate accounts, Stack Exchange doesn't accept users under the age of thirteen due to legal reasons. =/

Comment: Ah well this would answer it then. So I'll just ask his questions for him.

Comment: @YoungGuilo Yes, ask his questions for him. Even mention that you're asking for your brother (since that's relevant info for answerers: knowing that you're reporting the problem indirectly). Under no circumstances should you "ask his questions for him" by letting him use your account directly. You're still responsible for what happens on your account.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Your right and I will take that into account.